# I can buy a package of 2 black marbles and 1 white marble. How many packages do I have to buy until I have as many black marbles as white?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have 3 black marbles and 11 white marbles to start with. I'm really confused with questions like these.

Answer (score 5):

You have eight fewer black marbles than white.

With every package, you buy one black marble more than you buy white marbles.

Buying 8 packages you buy 8 black marbles more than white ones. Since you started with 8 black marbles fewer, you know have the same number of black and white marbles.

Comment: +1 for using thought instead of algebra. I think it's important to teach people that, in some situations, setting up and solving equations is overkill because the answer can be obtained by just thinking about the situation for a moment. (And I'd say this even if the question is an exercise in an algebra book.)

Answer (score 0):

If $k$ is the number of package; to have as much black marble than white, you need to find $k$ who satisfy

$$3+2k=11+k$$

Answer (score 0):

Let k be the number of packages you need to buy.

Initially, you have 3 black and 11 white marbles. 
With every package you get, the number of black marbles increases by 2, and the number of white marbles increases by 1.

If you buy one package, you'll have 5 black and 12 white marbles. Two packages would give you a total of 7 black and 13 white and so on...

**k** packages would give u **3 + 2k** and **11 + k**.

You want them equal, which means you want the solution to k where the above two **bold** numbers are equal.

That is, 3+ 2k = 11 + k
Solving that would give you **k=8**